# Unity debug error “Frame not in module”

Tags: unity, unity-ui, debugging

I'm creating a 2D game, and all my game layers are UI canvases. Here's the issue: during debugging, every time I click on the screen, Visual Studio stops and displays "Frame not in module," and I have to click "continue." It's abnormal because I didn't add breakpoints for each click.

Comment: The debugger should only pause "automatically" on unhandled exceptions... Something's gone wrong and you didn't deal with it. In a normal program, that would be the point where your application crashed. Unity will actually catch/hide those errors at runtime, but if they're happening, there's something wrong with your code. If it's happening per-frame, you're wasting a LOT of CPU time handling exceptions.

Comment: To help you troubleshoot this, we'll need you to walk through the steps to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the problem. Once we can reproduce the symptoms you're seeing, we can investigate root causes and test potential fixes. Try making a copy of your project and deleting everything you can without making the problem disappear — what's left after you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well It is solved by rebuild the whole program and close
all the files opened. Maybe it is because I open some unity source code and it does not has PDB file.